# Recursively finding the average of even numbers in an array

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

I'm trying to find the **average of all even numbers** in an array using **recursion** and I'm stuck.

I realize that `n` will have to be **decremented for each odd number** so I divide by the correct value, but I can't wrap my mind around how to do so with recursion.

I don't understand how to keep track of `n` as I go, considering it will just revert when I `return`.

Is there a way I'm missing to keep track of `n`, or am I looking at this the wrong way entirely?

EDIT: I should have specified, I need to use recursion specifically. It's an assignment.

```
public static int getEvenAverage(int[] A, int i, int n)
{
    // first element
    if (i == 0)
        if (A[i] % 2 == 0)
            return A[0];
        else
            return 0;

    // last element
    if (i == n - 1)
    {
        if (A[i] % 2 == 0)
            return (A[i] + getEvenAverage(A, i - 1, n)) / n;
        else
            return (0 + getEvenAverage(A, i - 1, n)) / n;
    }

    if (A[i] % 2 == 0)
        return A[i] + getEvenAverage(A, i - 1, n);
    else
        return 0 + getEvenAverage(A, i - 1, n);
}
```

Comment: If you mean by saying "looking at this the wrong way" by trying to solve it recursively, then yes. Is this some kind of homework assignment, you need to solve exactly the way you mentioned or can you use non-recursive operations as well? If the latter, using list.stream().filter(elem -> elem % 2 == 0).average() should do what you need

Comment: Why do you want to use recursion?

Comment: Also, you ask how to calculate the average of all even numbers but your implementation actually calculates the sum of all even numbers divided by the number of all elements of the list. That's different things. What do you need to actually calculate?

Comment: It's for an assignment. I was explicitly told to solve it recursively. I am essentially trying to figure out if that's possible, or if I misunderstood the requirements somehow.

Comment: I do need to calculate the average of all even numbers. That's the issue I'm having. I don't know how to divide by only the amount of even numbers.

Comment: Naming your variables more clearly might help the thinking process. You may need to add an extra parameter to keep track of the count of even elements.

Comment: Your current attempt is trying to do "divide-and-conquer", which would require pushing back two values (running sum and count), or you'd get an average-of-average result.  You'll probably find it easier to do it linearly.  You're going to need one more parameter than you have (you have to push all data _down_ for something like this, which is also likely to make it tail recursive).  The answer is also a lot **simpler** than you currently have; generally speaking, recursive functions check for one condition about the series: if you've reached the terminating condition.

Comment: What are you supposed to return if the array contains only odd numbers?

Comment: @pjs The average of all even numbers, so the same result as the average of an empty list (i.e. `0`). At least that's what I implicitly expected when reading the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to keep track of the number of even numbers you have encountered so far, just pass an extra parameter.

Moreover, you can also pass an extra parameter for the sum of even numbers and when you hit the base case you can return the average, that is, sum of even numbers divided by their count.

One more thing, your code has two base cases for the first as well as last element which is unneeded.

1. You can either go decrementing `n` ( start from size of array and go till the first element ), or
2. You can go incrementing `i` starting from `0` till you reach size of array, that is, `n`.

Here, is something I tried.

```
public static int getEvenAvg(int[] a, int n, int ct, int sum) {
    if (n == -1) {
        //make sure you handle the case
        //when count of even numbers is zero
        //otherwise you'll get Runtime Error.
        return sum/ct;
    }
    if (a[n]%2 == 0) {
        ct++;
        sum+=a[n];
    }
    return getEvenAvg(a, n - 1, ct, sum); 
}
```

You can call the function like this `getEvenAvg(a, size_of_array - 1, 0, 0);`

[Example](https://ideone.com/EFG7YM)

Comment: Well, yes, but why _backwards_?

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse. Just a matter of choice :). Also, another argument (index `i`) is needed, along with `n`, to check if we have reached the end of the array.

Comment: No?  The array knows how long it is, after all.

Comment: Ah. @Clockwork-Muse. Sorry about that. I'm not really a java guy :p. Forgot about `array.length`.

Comment: True, in something like C/C++ where basic array types don't have an inherent length element, counting backwards would remove the need to pass the (otherwise needed) extra parameter.

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with recursive operations, it's often useful to start with the terminating conditions.  So what are our terminating conditions here?

There are no more elements to process:

```
if (index >= a.length) {
    // To avoid divide-by-zero
    return count == 0 ? 0 : sum / count;
}
```

... okay, now how do we reduce the number of elements to process?  We should probably increment index?

```
index++;
```

... oh, but only when going to the next level:

```
getEvenAverage(elements, index++, sum, count);
```

Well, we're also going to have to add to `sum` and `count`, right?

```
sum += a[index];
count++;
```

.... except, only if the element is even:

```
if (a[index] % 2 == 0) {
    sum += a[index];
    count++;    
}
```

... and that's about it:

```
static int getEvenAverage(int[] elements, int index, int sum, int count) {
    if (index >= a.length) {
        // To avoid divide-by-zero
        return count == 0 ? 0 : sum / count;
    }

    if (a[index] % 2 == 0) {
        sum += a[index];
        count++;    
    } 

    return getEvenAverage(elements, index + 1, sum, count);
}
```

... although you likely want a wrapper function to make calling it prettier:

```
static int getEvenAverage(int[] elements) {
    return getEvenAverage(elements, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Explanation

The difficulties here are that you need to **memorize two values**:

- the amount of even numbers and
- the total value accumulated by the even numbers.

And you need to return a final value for an average.

This means that you need to memorize three values at once while only being able to return one element.

---

### Outline

For a clean design you need some kind of **container** that holds those intermediate results, for example a class like this:

```
public class Results {
    public int totalValueOfEvens;
    public int amountOfEvens;

    public double getAverage() {
        return totalValueOfEvens + 0.0 / amountOfEvens;
    }
}
```

Of course you could also use something like an `int[]` with two entries.

After that the recursion is very simple. You just need to **recursively traverse** the array, like:

```
public void method(int[] values, int index) {
    // Abort if last element
    if (index == values.length - 1) {
        return;
    }

    method(array, index + 1);
}
```

And while doing so, **update the container** with the current values.

---

### Collecting backwards

When collecting backwards you need to store all information in the **return value**.

As you have multiple things to remember, you should use a container as return type (`Results` or a `2`-entry `int[]`). Then simply traverse to the end, collect and return.

Here is how it could look like:

```
public static Results getEvenAverage(int[] values, int curIndex) {
    // Traverse to the end
    if (curIndex != values.length - 1) {
        results = getEvenAverage(values, curIndex + 1);
    }

    // Update container
    int myValue = values[curIndex];

    // Whether this element contributes
    if (myValue % 2 == 0) {
        // Update the result container
        results.totalValueOfEvens += myValue;
        results.amountOfEvens++;
    }

    // Return accumulated results
    return results;
}
```

---

### Collecting forwards

The advantage of this method is that the caller does not need to call `results.getAverage()` by himself. You store the information in the parameters and thus be able to freely choose the return type.

We get our current value and update the container. Then we call the next element and pass him the current container.

After the last element was called, the information saved in the container is final. We now simply need to end the recursion and return to the first element. When again visiting the first element, it will compute the final output based on the information in the container and return.

```
public static double getEvenAverage(int[] values, int curIndex, Results results) {
    // First element in recursion
    if (curIndex == 0) {
        // Setup the result container
        results = new Results();
    }

    int myValue = values[curIndex];

    // Whether this element contributes
    if (myValue % 2 == 0) {
        // Update the result container
        results.totalValueOfEvens += myValue;
        results.amountOfEvens++;
    }

    int returnValue = 0;
    // Not the last element in recursion
    if (curIndex != values.length - 1) {
        getEvenAverage(values, curIndex + 1, results);
    }

    // Return current intermediate average,
    // which is the correct result if current element
    // is the first of the recursion
    return results.getAverage();
}
```

---

### Usage by end-user

The backward method is used like:

```
Results results = getEvenAverage(values, 0);
double average results.getAverage();
```

Whereas the forward method is used like:

```
double average = getEvenAverage(values, 0, null);
```

Of course you can hide that from the user using a helper method:

```
public double computeEvenAverageBackward(int[] values) {
    return getEvenAverage(values, 0).getAverage();
}

public double computeEvenAverageForward(int[] values) {
    return getEvenAverage(values, 0, null);
}
```

Then, for the end-user, it is just this call:

```
double average = computeEvenAverageBackward(values);
```

Comment: :wince:  Yes, but I have a problem with updating `Results` as a side effect.  Recursion is almost always cleaner (and possibly can be turned into tail-call) if the **last** thing done is return off the recursive call.

Comment: Then I'd recommend using the second method, collecting backwards. This can be done more easy, I'll update the answer.

Comment: Yeah, but where does `results` even come from in the second answer?

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse It is created by the first element in the recursion. The caller just calls the method with `null`, it does not matter as the first element overrides the value. I've just updated the answer to show the usage of both methods for an end-user.

Comment: It's just a cleaner way of storing recursion results. One could also substitute it by two `int` parameters or, if storing in the return-type, by an `int[]` with two entries, as seen in other answers.

Answer (score 0):

Java is not a good language for this kind of thing but here we go:

```
public class EvenAverageCalculation {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
        System.out.println(getEvenAverage(array));
    }

    public static double getEvenAverage(int[] values) {
        return getEvenAverage(values, 0, 0);
    }

    private static double getEvenAverage(int[] values, double currentAverage, int nrEvenValues) {
        if (values.length == 0) {
            return currentAverage;
        }
        int head = values[0];
        int[] tail = new int[values.length - 1];
        System.arraycopy(values, 1, tail, 0, tail.length);
        if (head % 2 != 0) {
            return getEvenAverage(tail, currentAverage, nrEvenValues);
        }
        double newAverage = currentAverage * nrEvenValues + head;
        nrEvenValues++;
        newAverage = newAverage / nrEvenValues;
        return getEvenAverage(tail, newAverage, nrEvenValues);
    }
}
```

You pass the current average and the number of even elements so far to each the recursive call. The new average is calculated by multiplying the average again with the number of elements so far, add the new single value and divide it by the new number of elements before passing it to the next recursive call.

The way of recreating new arrays for each recursive call is the part that is not that good with Java. There are other languages that have syntax for splitting head and tail of an array which comes with a much smaller memory footprint as well (each recursive call leads to the creation of a new int-array with n-1 elements). But the way I implemented that is the classical way of functional programming (at least how I learned it in 1994 when I had similar assignments with the programming language Gofer ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Here's another variant, which uses a (moderately) well known recurrence relationship for averages:

> avg<sub>0</sub> = 0
>
> avg<sub>n</sub> = avg<sub>n-1</sub> + (x<sub>n</sub> - avg<sub>n-1</sub>) / n

where avg<sub>n</sub> refers to the average of n observations, and x<sub>n</sub> is the n<sup>th</sup> observation.
This leads to:

```
/*
 * a is the array of values to process
 * i is the current index under consideration
 * n is a counter which is incremented only if the current value gets used
 * avg is the running average
 */
private static double getEvenAverage(int[] a, int i, int n, double avg) {
   if (i >= a.length) {
      return avg;
   }
   if (a[i] % 2 == 0) {         // only do updates for even values
      avg += (a[i] - avg) / n;  // calculate delta and update the average
      n += 1;
   }
   return getEvenAverage(a, i + 1, n, avg);
 }
```

which can be invoked using the following front-end method to protect users from needing to know about the parameter initialization:

```
public static double getEvenAverage(int[] a) {
   return getEvenAverage(a, 0, 1, 0.0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

And now for a completely different approach.

This one draws on the fact that if you have two averages, avg<sub>1</sub> based on n<sub>1</sub> observations and avg<sub>2</sub> based on n<sub>2</sub> observations, you can combine them to produce a pooled average:

> avg<sub>pooled</sub> = (n<sub>1</sub> * avg<sub>1</sub> + n<sub>2</sub> * avg<sub>2</sub>) / (n<sub>1</sub> + n<sub>2</sub>).

The only issue here is that the recursive function should return two values, the average and the number of observations on which that average is based. In many other languages, that's not a problem.  In Java, it requires some hackery in the form of a trivial, albeit slightly annoying, helper class:

```
   // private helper class because Java doesn't allow multiple returns
   private static class Pair {
      public double avg;
      public int n;

      public Pair(double avg, int n) {
         super();
         this.avg = avg;
         this.n = n;
      }      
   }
```

Applying a divide and conquer strategy yields the following recursion:

```
   private static Pair getEvenAverage(int[] a, int first, int last) {
      if (first == last) {
         if (a[first] % 2 == 0) {
            return new Pair(a[first], 1);
         }
      } else {
         int mid = (first + last) / 2;
         Pair p1 = getEvenAverage(a, first, mid);
         Pair p2 = getEvenAverage(a, mid + 1, last);
         int total = p1.n + p2.n;
         if (total > 0) {
            return new Pair((p1.n * p1.avg + p2.n * p2.avg) / total, total);
         }
      }
      return new Pair(0.0, 0);
    }
```

We can deal with empty arrays, protect the end-user from having to know about the book-keeping arguments, and return just the average by using the following public front-end:

```
   public static double getEvenAverage(int[] a) {
      return a.length > 0 ? getEvenAverage(a, 0, a.length - 1).avg : 0.0;
   }
```

This solution has the benefit of O(log n) stack growth for an array of n items, versus O(n) for the various other solutions that have been proposed. As a result, it can deal with much larger arrays without fear of a stack overflow.